# GWT : fileUpload.getFileName() & fakepath

Tags: java, gwt, cross-platform

I am working on a GWT project (web application) :

at some point, users can upload a file through the application via a FormPanel.

As I need the filename, I thought I could use :

```
    FileUpload upload = new FileUpload();
    // ...
    String name = upload.getFileName();
```

And `name` turns out to be something like this : `C:\fakepath\whatever.txt`.

Is this cross-platform ? What happens on other OS (I am using Windows) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name returned by a upload form is dependent on the browser's security settings.

On windows, the C:\fakepath is used to obscure where the file is actually located. The filename, however, is always kept.

The same can happen on other os'es, it wouldn't be C:\fakepath (not 100% sure anymore what linux could return, for example).

I'm currently working on a GWT-based system too, using the `FileUpload`; and the filename hasn't been wrong on any of the used client os'es (only different (fake)paths). This was used on Windows, Ubuntu and OS/x. You should be able to safely get the correct filename by separating on the last "/" or "\" (do note that those differ per OS), or use the `getFileName` method for that :).

Comment: The `C:\fakepath` prefix is ["by spec" in HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/number-state.html#file-upload-state). Expect all browsers, on all OSes, to update their behavior soon if not done already. The `extractFilename` JavaScript function from the HTML5 spec is easy to port to Java.